# NHibernate thinks I have a duplicate object when using SaveOrUpdate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I have a parent class

```
public class Parent
{
    public Parent(DateTime? date) { Date = date; }

    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }

    public void Save()
    {
        foreach(var child in Children)
        {
            child.Save(Date ?? DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, I also have a child class, and the the real cause for my issue:

```
public class Child
{
    public Child () {}

    public Decision FirstDecision { get; set;}

    public Decision SecondDecision { get; set; }

    public OtherProperty SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }

    public void Save(DateTime date)
    {
        SaveFirstDecision(date);
        SaveSecondDecision(date);
    }

    public void SaveFirstDecision(date)
    {
        var type = FactoryTools.Factory.CreateQueryable<DecisionType>()
                       .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name = "First");


        if(FirstDecision == null) FirstDecision = new Decision { Type = type };

        FirstDecision.SomeOtherPropery = SomeOtherProperty;
        FirstDecision.SomeDate = date;

        FactoryTools.Factory.SaveOrUpdate(FirstDecision);
    }

    public void SaveSecondDecision(date)
    {
        var type = FactoryTools.Factory.CreateQueryable<DecisionType>()
                       .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name = "Second");


        if(SecondDecision == null) SecondDecision = new Decision { Type = type };

        SecondDecision.SomeOtherPropery = SomeOtherProperty;
        SecondDecision.SomeDate = date;

        // This is where the Exception occurs
        FactoryTools.Factory.SaveOrUpdate(SecondDecision);
    }
}
```

So on the second SaveOrUpdate, NHibernate throws this exception:
`Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.d_decision' with unique index 'd_decision_i1'.`

I do not understand why NHibernate sees these two decisions as duplicates... I have tried many things, including overriding the `Equals` and `HashCode` but can not seem to avoid this issue. Thanks for your help.

Btw, the classes shown here are but abstractions of what I believe to be the relevant pieces of code, there are other properties in these classes, but I do not believe they are relevant...

Comment: that's not nhibernate seeing duplicates, that's the database seeing duplicates. what is your id generator set as?

Comment: the `Id` column is a `Primary Key`, `Identity: yes`, `Increment: 1`, `Seed: 1` mapped as: `Id(x => x.Id, map => { map.Column("id"); map.Generator(Generators.Identity); });`

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed out by Darren Kopp, this was an issue with the database. One of our dba's created an Index on that table that required that in a certain combination of columns, at least one had to be different...